# Retrieve query from django ORM with related fields

Tags: python, django

I created a Company in my django app, two or more person can login with the same company. I want to show the data of one user of the company to the other user of the company.

To simplify: If one user of a company creates an object, then it should be visible to all the users of that company

But I am having trouble extracting the data

Models.py

```
class ItemBatch(models.Model):
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pid = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ship_company')


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_supplier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(default=False)

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Views.py

```
class allordersview(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
  queryset = ItemBatch.objects.all()
  serializer_class = holdSerializer

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

      queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

      queryset = queryset.filter(uploaded_by_id=request.user) # ??Changes?? 
      .
      .
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

How to change the queryset such that it shows all ItemBatch of a Company ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
queryset.filter(uploaded_by__teacher__company=request.user.teacher.company)
```

PS: Instead of overriding `list` method override `get_queryset` method and apply filter there like

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return ItemBatch.objects.filter(uploaded_by__teacher__company=self.request.user.teacher.company)
```